# Python CSV library returning 1 item instead of a list of items

Tags: python, list, csv

Im trying to use the CSV library to do some excel processing, but when I use the code posted below, row returns the entirety of data as 1 item, so row[0] returns the entire file and row[1] returns index out of range. Is there a way to make each row a list with each cell being an item? Making the final product a list of lists. I was thinking of using split everytime ther was a close bracket ']' . If needed I can post the excel file

Heres a sample of what some of the output looks like. This is all one item in the list:

```
['3600035671,"$13,668",8/11/2008,8/11/2013,,,2,4A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,']
['3910435005,"$34,872",4/1/2010,10/8/2016,,,2,4A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,']
['5720636344,"$1,726",8/30/2010,9/5/2011,,,3,6C,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,']
['15260473510,"-$1,026,580",7/22/2005,3/5/2008,,,6,1C2A,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,']


import csv    
csvfile = open('Invictus.csv', 'rU')
data = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)    
for char in data:
    char = filter(None, char)
    print char
```

Comment: The csv file also has `[` and `]`?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? The output prints the [ and ] but its all one list item, so those 4 lines should be 4 items but instead its 1

Comment: The absurdly-named `char` is in fact a `list` (of strings) with a single item (because you said the separator was a tab while it's clearly a comma!-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are giving examples of your data above the line `import csv`, it looks like your data is comma delimited but you are setting up your CSV reader to expect tab delimited data (`dialect=csv.excel_tab`).

What happens if you change that line to:

```
data = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Can you please tell me why that is the case?

Comment: @FullCombatBeard, because commas are not tabs.  Why did you specify tabs in the first place?!

Comment: `excel_tab` is for TAB-delimited files produced by Excel, you might have thought it stood for "Excel table" I guess?

Comment: I was using the example in the documentation! I had no idea haha

Comment: Comma Separated Value (CSV) files are, confusingly, not always _comma_ separated. Sometimes, the fields are separated by something else, like a tab character. The lack of standards also means it can be hard for the CSV reader to figure out what kind of file you are actually dealing with. `excel_tab` is for tab separated fields, `excel` is for comma separated fields.

Comment: @FullCombatBeard, if you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it as the solution :)